# Question about changing a data type in python

Tags: python, types

Whilst trying to change the data types to add them, I noticed I can change a `str` to a `int` inside other commands but not solely by starting with `int`.

my code is below and includes my notes about what would work and what wouldn't to change the users string input to a `int` and was wondering if someone could explain why `int(first_num)` doesn't work to change the type

```
two_digit_number = input("Type a two digit number: ")

print(type(two_digit_number))

#This works for changing data type
first_num = int(two_digit_number[0])
second_num = int(two_digit_number[1])

#This does not work?
int(first_num)
int(second_num)

#This works for changing data type
print(int(first_num) + int(second_num))
```

Comment: `int(first_num)` doesn't assign any name to it `=`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #This does not work?
> int(first_num)
> int(second_num)
> ```

Works fine... You're just not storing the results anywhere. Strings are immutable, and this doesn't change the references of the names or modify the values *in-place*; `int()` function *returns* a new value.

Also, those two variable names *already* refer to integers.

Comment: I see its the not storing that's the issue, I know I did the same thing multiple times. I was playing around with what works. Thank you for the help